# Refused to execute script from '***' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: ajax, javascript

I am facing some UI issues with my wordpress website. The newly added "Author" role is not able to see the formatting toolbar while writing the post. After debugging, I found a javascript error which I suppose is due to the update of version 4.4.2.

The error (below snip) is this:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://www.faksite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=themeSome_shortcode_editor_plugin&wp-mce-4208-20151113' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Cant figure out what is the issue.

[image]

Comment: guys im getting this same error and my whole site is gone style-less and take ages to laod , any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: I encountered such an error when enabled X-Content-Security-Policy:nosniff HTTP header.

Answer (score 2):

The error is most likely correct (and is most likely related to browser upgrade than any WP version change) and your theme/plugin does fishy things. The ajax enedpoint should be uses to return data - html/json/xml.

Wordpress will use the text/html mime type for all responses from the ajax endpoint without any simple way I can see to override it.

In addition to your existing problem, the ajax endpoint is blocked to search engines so you might be hurting your SEO if this code is used on the front end.

If it is not a theme you develop yourself, you should contact the theme/plugin author to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Be aware of malicious script!

1) Can you tell us,  which site is that exactly?

There is a big chance, that you have a fishy theme or plugin installed, which tries to send some data to 3rd party site, and it may inject malicious scripts on your site...

2) Even if you trust your plugins/theme, check, which one fires that line is not needed at all. Find out and disable the plugin that does that.

3) **IN CASE YOU TRUST WHAT HAPPENS WITH YOU**, then you should go to that `faksite.com` and in output of `ajax` call, insert special `header(content-type: text/javascript)` before output.